# How can I limit the number of objects fetched from a Parse.com collection (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, collections

Can I do anything from here to limit the number of objects that are returned? By default, it is 100 and I don't need that many for now. Anyway to just fetch the most recent 10 objects in that class?

```
var Blog = Parse.Object.extend("Blog");

var Blogs = Parse.Collection.extend({
    model: Blog
});

var blogs = new Blogs();

blogs.fetch({
    success: function(blogs) {
        var blogsView = new BlogsView({ collection: blogs });
        blogsView.render();
        $('.main-container').html(blogsView.el);
    },
    error: function(blogs, error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the backbone `fetch` doc:

> jQuery.ajax options can also be passed directly as fetch options, so
>   to fetch a specific page of a paginated collection:
>   Documents.fetch({data: {page: 3}})

For setting the number of objects returned, the option name is `limit`, so:

```
blogs.fetch({ data: {limit: 10}, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
Blogs = Parse.Collection.extend({
    model: Blog,
    query: (new Parse.Query(Blog)).descending('createdAt').limit(10),
}),
```

...and showed the newest objects first by sorting by descending order.